# Google + Community- Inviting people to private group

Tags: google-plus, invitation

When I try to invite someone to a my private Google+ community it doesn't send them an email. It opens up a post window with there email in it. Then if I hit post it said: "Can't invite people who are already members or who are not allowed."

What's going on here. I would have thought it would simply sent them an email with a link. I haven't been able to invite anyone yet.